# How to nest dependent Jenkins Pipelines to execute on a single machine?

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline

We are implementing Continuous Integration of several repositories using Jenkins.

For this example, let's assume *libA* is a dependency of *libB* which is a dependency of *clientC*.

### libA pipeline

*libA* has external dependencies, so we can write the **pipeline** *build-A-pipe* to build it : one of the stages being responsible for gathering such dependencies, and a subsequent stage actually invoking the build command.

### libB pipeline

*libB* would ideally be built within a separate **pipeline**, called *build-B-pipe*. In the stage to gather *libB* dependencies, we have to build *libA*. It seems to us that the best way to achieve such thing is to call `build job: 'build-A-pipe'` within the pipeline that builds *libB* (this way it allows to reuse the *build-A-pipe*, which already describes all steps required to successfully build *libA*).

### clientC pipeline

Now, if we wanted to build *clientC*, we would follow a similar procedure. Thus, there would be a call like `build job: 'build-B-pipe'` in the dependencies gathering stage of the pipeline building *clientC*. The issue is that **it results in nested calls** to the `build` command, which deadlocks the single machine :

- at the top level calling `build job: 'build-B-pipe'` schedules *build-B-pipe*, and starts it on the master machine (our only "execution node").
- *build-B-pipe* then calls `build job: 'build-A-pipe'`, which is then scheduled but cannot start, as the only "execution node" is already taken.

How should we approach this problem to make this inherently sequential build work within Jenkins ?

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that it results in nested calls to the build command, which deadlocks the single machine

By deadlock, do you mean that the slave agent which is responsible for executing the nested pipeline is running out of resources? Or is the node which is responsible for running these nested pipelines running out of executors?

If the machine responsible for running pipelines is exhausting all resources (assuming that this is the only responsibility of this machine), then your pipeline is too complex and should delegate more to other nodes/agents.

If the node is running out of executors, you can increase those in the node config.